# R ggplot2 - How do I specify out of bounds values' colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the plot generated by the following code I would like to alter the colours so that all values < 0.6 are the same as the "low" colour and all values greater than 1 are the "high" colour.

As is stands the colour gradient stretches across the entire numeric range of the data. I have tried adding limits but that makes all out of bounds value the same colour as NA values, which is not what I want because I need missing NA values to clearly stick out and not look the same colour as out of bounds values <0.6.

I'm convinced that the answer is with the oob, breaks arguments but have had no success getting it to work.

```
library(ggplot2)
a = rnorm(17*17, 0.733,0.21)
qcMat = matrix(a, ncol = 17)
qcMat[qcMat> 1] = 1
#qcMat contains values between 0 and 1 and some NAs

m = melt(t(qcMat))
m$Var2 <- with(m,factor(Var2, levels = rev(sort(unique(Var2)))))
ggplot(m, aes(as.factor(Var1), Var2, group=Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_text(aes(fill = m$value, label = round(m$value, 2))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  xlab("") + ylab("") + ggtitle(paste("biscuit:", biscuit_id, "- QC", sep = " "))
```

Comment: You write 'all values greater than 1 are the "high" colour' and 'qcMat contains values between 0 and 1 and some NAs'. Why use 1 as a limit when you don't have any 1 in your data?

Comment: @Henrik the data generated for the purpose of this snippet is not a true reflection of the real data on which I am working, but its pretty close. Also fixed the removal of dishMat.

Comment: You could also set the `na.value` like this: `scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", na.value = "hotpink")`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As you said youself, you want the `oob` argument in the `scale_fill_gradient`. To clamp values, you can use [squish from the scales package](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/scales/html/squish.html) (`scales` is installed when `ggplot2` is installed):

```
library(scales)
```

and later

```
scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green", limits=c(0.6, 1), oob=squish)
```

Comment: Brilliant! I hadn't loaded the scales package, but i had tried this exact fix other than that. So close but no cigar. Cheers Stefan!

Comment: I don't understand this example. Where is it that you specify the color of the values out of range? This just makes it the values not to be considered as NA

Comment: This is great.  `squish` in this context converts clamps all values to be within the min and max of the `limits` argument. i.e., if value < min(limits) then value = min(limits) else if value > max(limits) then value = max(limits).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `geom_tile` to below:

```
  geom_tile(aes(fill = ifelse(value<0.6,min(m$value,na.rm=TRUE),
                              ifelse(value>1,max(m$value,na.rm=TRUE),
                                     value))))
```

**EDIT:** Then don't use min max, so we will get 0.6-1 range:

```
geom_tile(aes(fill = ifelse(value<0.6,0.6,
                            ifelse(value>1,1,
                                   value))))
```

Comment: Thanks zx8754 this is definitely a step in the right direct, but not quite perfect, I have updated my question to reflect you suggest and clarified the new problem it presents. Cheers!

Comment: Updated question. This is closer still, but not quite perfect. I really appreciate your help with this I don't suppose you are a Dogecoin user that I could tip?