# R ggplot2 points on a shape continuous scale (scale_fill_gradient) with limits and outliers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting some climate simulations as raster on a world map using ggplot2.
I am giving a continuous scale to the represented values setting a range in the scale_fill_gradient(). 
The maps are more than one and I need to make them comparable: that for, I need to give the same range to all of the variables represented. Majority of the data for each variable is distributed in the range (-1.5,1.5), range that I am choosing for the scale.
My problem is related to the outliers. Using these settings, I get them in the map in a neutral color (grey), while I would like to have them represented with the same color of the min/max boundary of the scale.

Data are available at this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qmzkuvl7gkidql1/AAClIlr-Z7i2tf98U6eq0h5ra?dl=0)

here is my code

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(raster)
library(grid)

setwd("myfolder")
world<-readOGR("TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp", layer="TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3")
world=fortify(world, region="ISO3")

raster<-stack("d_spi24_neg45")
r_points = rasterToPoints(raster)
r_df = data.frame(r_points)

summary(r_df[,3])
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-3.30000 -0.30000  0.00000 -0.05307  0.20000  2.50000
ggplot(data=r_df) + 
geom_tile(aes(x=x,y=y, fill=d_spi24_neg45))+
scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(-1.5, +1.5), low="blue", high="red")+
coord_equal() +
theme_bw() +
theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.background=element_blank(),
    panel.border=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
    plot.background=element_blank(),
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.text=element_text(size=10),
    legend.key.height=unit(0.25,"cm"),
    legend.key.width=unit(2,"cm"),
    legend.title=element_blank())+
geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group), color = "black", 
           fill="transparent", size = 0.25)+ xlim(-165, 180) + ylim(-58,85)
```

My result, as you can see (north California for instance) I have grey values in correspondence with the outliers:
[image]

I see two solutions:
the first (not my preferred) would be to squeeze the data in the represented range with something like:

```
r_df$d_spi24_neg85[r_df$d_spi24_neg85 < -1.5] <- -1.5
r_df$d_spi24_neg85[r_df$d_spi24_neg85 > 1.5] <- 1.5
```

**Edit**: this first solution is better addressed using:

```
scale_fill_gradient(limits=c(-1.5, +1.5), low="blue", high="red", oob=squish)+
```

as suggested by jlhoward in the comments referring to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653951/r-ggplot2-how-do-i-specify-out-of-bounds-values-colour) . **End Edit**

The second solution would be maybe a logarithmic scale centered in my range??? Open to suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Try `scale_fill_gradient(..., oob=squish)` (`squish` is from the `scales` package). See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653951/r-ggplot2-how-do-i-specify-out-of-bounds-values-colour), and please upvote the answer there if it solves your problem.

Comment: Hi  jlhoward. Yes, at least in part: it does the trick, but the result is the same as the one that I suggested with the solution number one. Of course this is way more elegant than what I suggested. However I was more interested in a different approach, able to show also the weight of the outliers. That's the reason why I was suggesting a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Btw, I gave a +1 to both your comment and the answer you mentioned.