# Using oob to change value to a another color in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am checking this post: [R ggplot2 - How do I specify out of bounds values' colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653951/r-ggplot2-how-do-i-specify-out-of-bounds-values-colour) on how to "Specify out of bounds values to color".

The answer given was using `obs=squish`, but that doesn't let you specify a color that is out of range. In my example, it just uses the closest color in my range of values. What if I want to highlight those with another one?

**Example:**

Here all the values out of range as well as NA are treated as NA and are coloured as grey.

```
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100, 3, 1), ncol=10)
dat.m <- melt(dat)
dat.m[c(1,5,10),3] <- NA 

ggplot(dat.m, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
  scale_fill_continuous("",limits=c(1,2), low = "#d73027",
                        high = "#4575b4", na.value = "grey")
```

But now I want all the values that are out of range to have another color, say white, but `NA` still with grey. If I use `oob=squish`, it just colors them to the closest value, but where can I specify a color?

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
  scale_fill_continuous("",limits=c(1,2), low = "#d73027",
                        high = "#4575b4", na.value = "grey",oob=squish)
```

Comment: What if I just change NA to white and then is there a way to manually select which cells to color? That way I could select the NA and coloured them as grey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easiest to just use two `geom_tile`s and rely on overplotting for the true `NA` values:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(factor(Var1), factor(Var2))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile(fill = 'grey', data = subset(dat.m, is.na(value))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
  scale_fill_continuous("",limits=c(1,2), low = "#d73027",
                        high = "#4575b4", na.value = "lightgreen") +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]