# Scale color gradient and AND outside the limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used this Question ([ggplot scale color gradient to range outside of data range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888222/ggplot-scale-color-gradient-to-range-outside-of-data-range)) to create a gradient within a specific range but now I have the problem, that all colors outside these limits are grey. I mean, it is logic to me but I wanted to have those to have the same color as the closest point.

```
ggplot(data.frame(a=1:10), aes(1, a, color=a)) + 
  geom_point(size=6) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=c('red','yellow','green'), limits=c(2,8))
```

So the top points should be green and the lower point should be red as well.
So what I am looking for is a range like `limits=c(<2,>8)` but I know this is not working

Comment: Workaround can be: `color = ifelse(a < 2, 2, ifelse(a > 8, 8, a))`

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23655697/1527403

Comment: Ahh - I see someone has answered..incidentally I think this should be documented better in the scale_colour_gradient page - where oob is mentioned but not explained or demonstrated.

Comment: This option never jumped into my eyes... Will have a look into some documentation, I might need this more often!

Comment: @StephenHenderson Agreed; if you type `scales::squish` you see that the function basically does the same as what @PoGibas suggested. It can also be used as a template for writing your own functions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can specify how to deal with out-of-bounds values via argument `oob`; for example, `scales::squish` "squishes" values into the range specified by `limits`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(a=1:10), aes(1, a, color = a)) +
    geom_point(size = 6) +
    scale_colour_gradientn(
        colours=c('red','yellow','green'), 
        limits=c(2,8), 
        oob = scales::squish);
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! :-D This is what I was looking for! Have never seen the `oob` parameter!